# MUI Grid System to Take Up 100% of Width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-grid

hope you're all good.

I'm having an issue finding out how to make my MUI Grid take up the entire width of the Box component it is nested within.

Here is how it looks:
[image: MUI Grid not taking up entire width]

I want the empty space at the end right to be taken up by the entire grid but I can't seem to find a concise answer on how to fix this.

Here is my code in VS Code:

[image: Grid Code]

Here is the code in text for the Grid:

```
<Grid item key={days}>
        <Box
          key={days}
          sx={{
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            backgroundColor: 'primary.dark',
            '&:hover': {
              backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
              opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
            },
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    );
  }
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={1}>
      {/* And here I render the box array */}
      {box}
    </Grid>
  );
```

And here is the parent elements:
[image: Parent Elements]

Here is the code in real text for the parent elements:

```
// Parent Element
    <Container>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          width: 1,
        }}
      >
        {/* The Title of The Page */}
        <Typography align="center" variant="h4" mt={2} mb={2} sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
          {t('Happy Chocolate Days!')}
        </Typography>
        {/* My Calendar Grid Component Inside The Box Component */}
        <Calendar />
      </Box>
    </Container>
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the boxes to a fixed width & height of `150`, thus even though their wrapper has more space left, there is not enough space for another box so it breaks into a new line, thus leaving you with the empty space on the right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what can I do to fix this? Cause I want the boxes to look like a calendar day, I tried removing the width attribute but that didn't give me the result I needed

Comment: Well, you either need to make the spacing between the boxes non-fixed, you are using `spacing={1}`, which would increase the space between the boxes, or you can  just center the boxes within the wrapper and not care about the bit of space on the side.

Answer (score 1):

You either set the boxes all of them in the middle of the `Container`,
OR pick a `width` for the `Container` that can have `7 boxes` of the same `width` with some space between them, like 770px width for container, and `10px` spaces between them. but in that case you wont need `Grid`, just pure css.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, much appreciated taking your time :)